# Upsource Webhooks and JIRA

Tags: jira, upsource

I am working on automating the code review process in my team.

My objectives are:

1. When a review is created, assign it to two random developers
2. Automatically update the JIRA item, and assign them to the developers who were assigned as reviewers in Upsource

I was able to achieve objective #1 using [Upsource Custom Workflows](https://blog.jetbrains.com/upsource/2016/06/28/custom-workflows/).

For the second objective, I have tried looking at [Upsource Webhooks](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/upsource/2017.1/upsource-webhooks.html) and JIRA [Cloud REST API](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/), but I fail to see how to assign a JIRA item from Upsource. JIRA's API specifies that in order to assign an item using REST, we need to create PUT request to this method:

`PUT /rest/api/2/issue/{issueIdOrKey}/assignee`

- How can I create a PUT request from Upsource Webhooks?
- How can I extract the {issueIDOrKey} from the originating Upsource review?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I create a PUT request from Upsource Webhooks?

Upsource webhooks send only POST requests at the moment. But I don't see how this limitation is blocking your task, because as I understand there has to be a service that'll translate Upsource payload to JIRA payload. That service should make a PUT request.

> How can I extract the {issueIDOrKey} from the originating Upsource review?

Upsource provides an [API](https://upsource.jetbrains.com/~api_doc/reference/Service.html#messages.UpsourceRPC) for this. `getReviewDetails` method allows to get a list of issues associated with a given review (see this [message spec](https://upsource.jetbrains.com/~api_doc/reference/Projects.html#messages.ReviewDescriptorDTO)).